# TrueCrypt fails with fusefs kext error

Tags: macos, kernel, truecrypt, kernel-extensions

After upgrading to Mountain Lion, I can't mount any volumes with *TrueCrypt* 7.1a anymore.  After typing in the password for the volume, an error message is shown, stating that the `fusefs kext can't be loaded`.

The system log file shows the following errors:

```
com.apple.kextd[12]: Failed to load /Library/Filesystems/fusefs.fs/Support/fusefs.kext - (libkern/kext) link error.
kernel[0]: kxld[com.google.filesystems.fusefs]: The following symbols are unresolved for this kext:
kernel[0]: kxld[com.google.filesystems.fusefs]:    _OSRuntimeFinalizeCPP
kernel[0]: kxld[com.google.filesystems.fusefs]:    _OSRuntimeInitializeCPP
kernel[0]: Can't load kext com.google.filesystems.fusefs - link failed.
kernel[0]: Failed to load executable for kext com.google.filesystems.fusefs.
kernel[0]: Kext com.google.filesystems.fusefs failed to load (0xdc008016).
kernel[0]: Failed to load kext com.google.filesystems.fusefs (error 0xdc008016).
```

Do I need to update *MacFuse* or *TrueCrypt* to make this work again?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It turned out that this was related to running a true 64-bit kernel instead of a 32/64-bit one.

Installing one of the following updates for the FuseFS system fixed the error:

- Fuse for OSX: http://osxfuse.github.com/
- MacFuse 2.2.2: http://mac.majorgeeks.com/files/details/macfuse.html

After installing this, I reopened TrueCrypt and was then able to mount the volume.

Answer (score 0):

Version **7.1a** of `TrueCrypt`

- does install,
- is PGP verified,
- and does run
  on `Mountain Lion`.

The installer does install the correct kernel extensions:[image]